# What is the meaning of *[Symbol.iterator] in this context

Tags: javascript

I found some code online. I've squashed the original code down into this little excerpt, that when ran, will print 1-20 to the console.

```
var NumbersFromOne = {
  *[Symbol.iterator] () {
    for (let i = 1;; ++i) yield i;
  }
};

var take = function* (numberToTake, iterable) {
  let remaining = numberToTake;

  for (let value of NumbersFromOne) {
    if (remaining-- <= 0) break;
    yield value;
  }
}


var printToTwenty = take(20, NumbersFromOne)

console.log(...printToTwenty);
```

Now, I understand that take() is a GeneratorFunction.
When take() is called, it is given an iterator.
The code "...printToTwenty" uses the spread operator to iterate through that function.

I understand that NumbersFromOne is an object.
I've come here looking for an explanation of what this part means:

```
*[Symbol.iterator] () {}
```

Declaring generator functions is done like this: function* () {} 
So I'm assuming this isn't declaring a generator function.

* also doesn't represent the function name 
* also can't be replaced with another operator (/, -, +)

What is the deal with that syntax, and why is the * before [Symbol.iterator] 
If placed after, it will not run. 
I had considered that *[Symbol.iterator] () is a way to overwrite the existing iterator property, but then wouldn't it say this[Symbol.iterator].

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a few things that might make this code look complicated:

It uses the object property shorthand notation. What you're seeing here is actually the following:

```
var NumbersFromOne = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    for (let i = 1;; ++i) yield i;
  }
};
```

[`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) creates a custom iterator for your `NumbersFromOne` object.

**So your code basically means that the iterator of `NumbersFromOne` is defined as a generator.** Instead of manually having to define a function which returns a next and other properties:

```
var NumbersFromOne = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
    var i = 1;
    return {
        next: function() {
            return { value: i++, done: false };
        }
    };
  }
};
```

Returning the generator creates the `next` function automatically for. This allows you to yield when you need to.

It can then be called as:

```
const it = NumbersFromOne[Symbol.iterator]();
it.next(); // 1
it.next(); // 2
it.next(); // 3
// ...
```

**Note:** Written this way, this iterator never ends! So if you were to call it in a `for ... of` loop without an end-condition, it would freeze your program.

Comment: I like this answer. I want to point out though, that the * has to come after the function. I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://www.es6fiddle.net/inpoxsps/ I was not aware of that being the short-hand notation. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: Whoops, my bad, thank you for pointing this out. I haven't had the chance to write all that many real-world generators yet. Now it should work :)

Comment: Hey Nils - Why the need for two iterators here, take & numbersfromone. Take seems redundant if you could just get a range in numbersfromone, no?

Comment: Hey James, `take` is not part of my answer. It just provides an superfluous layer of iteration. I don't see a reason to use it either.

Comment: @nils I have just seen the usage of `Symbol.iterator` in a code snippet. But I don't get why it's used there. The code is iterating over an array of objects using the iterator, but I don't see any reason not to use a `for loop`. What's the difference? Performance?